# How do I view the HTML Dom afer a jQuery modification?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am using DebugBar in IE to view the DOM.  But after I modify the DOM with jQuery I can not see the new or modified DOM with DebugBar.  How Do I view the modified DOM?

Comment: I think you can't do. Because is saved in memory and rendered by browser javascript engine. But if anyone know howto i appreciate the answer.

Comment: Assuming IE important? Otherwise, well firebug, right...

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about IE, but the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension for [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/firefox.html?from=getfirefox) lets you view the changes and even displays then in a really user friendly way. Even if you must test in IE, you can always switch to using Firefox when you really need this functionality in developing your code.

Searching around I also found this piece of info for IE7:

> IE7Pro just right click and choose View
>   Generated Source.

Answer (score 1):

There are few options as listed on IE Team's blog.

http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/05/10/416156.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I can view the modified DOM with DebugBar and with MS  Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar  after refreshing or reloading the DOM

Answer (score 1):

You can use IE "Developer Tools," available in IE8 by default (F12 to launch) and available in IE7 via download from Microsoft.  In the developer tools window, after pressing refresh, you'll see the in-memory version of the DOM in the HTML tab.